# How can I use existing JProgressBar in SftpProgressMonitor instance?

Tags: java, swing, sftp, jsch

I am writing a program that downloads a file from a server using SFTP. I'd like to have a progress bar on the program that reflects the download progress. Here is my current code for the progress monitor:

```
public class SystemOutProgressMonitor implements SftpProgressMonitor
{
    public SystemOutProgressMonitor() {;}

    public void init(int op, java.lang.String src, java.lang.String dest, long max) 
    {
        System.out.println("STARTING: "+op+" "+src+" -> "+dest+" total: "+max);
    }

    public boolean count(long bytes)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<bytes;x++) {
            System.out.println("#");
        }
        return(true);
    }

    public void end()
    {
        System.out.println("\nFINISHED!");
    }
}
```

This works fine for outputting to the console, however, I do not know how to pass the existing progress bar variable to this.

The JProgressBar that I am using resides in my Menu.java class, in this class there is a download button that calls the corresponding download method in my Sftp.java class, from there, the SystemOutProgressMonitor is called by:

```
sftpChannel.get(target, destination, new SystemOutProgressMonitor());
```

So would I pass the progress bar from Menu.java to Sftp.java, and then to SystemOutProgressMonitor?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`ProgressMonitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html)

Otherwise you'll need a `SwingWorker` or use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to ensure that the updates to the `JProgressBar` are synchronized to the Event Dispatching Thread correctly.

Take a look at:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

for more details

Comment: all I'm trying to do is set the value of the existing progress bar within the count method of SystemOutProgressMonitor, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but since you've not provided any code that shows that it's difficult to know what to suggest or even what the problem is.  See the second paragraph for what you will need to do to ensure you don't violate the single thread rules of Swing